# httpd24 by scl doesn't render php

Tags: apache-2.4, php7

I have installed httpd24 with php72 by scl in a CentOS 6.10 x86-64 environment. But Apache doesn't render php files and display them as text.

Installed php using,

```
yum install php72-php php72-php-iconv php72-php-mbstring php72-php-curl php72-php-openssl php72-php-tokenizer php72-php-xmlrpc php72-php-soap php72-php-ctype php72-php-zip php72-php-gd php72-php-simplexml php72-php-spl php72-php-pcre php72-php-dom php72-php-xml php72-php-xml php72-php-intl php72-php-json php72-php-mysqlnd php72-php-ldap
```

When I run,

```
apachectl -M | grep php
```

Output:

> php7_module (shared)

When I run,

```
php -v
```

Output:

> PHP 7.2.14 (cli) (built: Jan 8 2019 11:55:37) ( NTS )
>   Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
>   Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies

There was no php72-php.conf file created in /opt/rh/httpd24/root/etc/httpd/conf.d/ at the time of php72 installation. The php72-php.conf file was created in /etc/httpd/conf.d/ instead.

When I try to manually copy the php72-php.conf file to /opt/rh/httpd24/root/etc/httpd/conf.d/, it won't allow me to restart httpd24-httpd service and gives the below error;

> Stopping httpd:    [  OK  ]
>   Starting httpd: httpd: Syntax error on line 353 of /opt/rh/httpd24/root/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf : Syntax error on line 9 of /opt/rh/httpd24/root/etc/httpd/conf.d/php72-php.conf : Cannot load modules/libphp72.so into server: /opt/rh/httpd24/root/etc/httpd/modules/libphp72.so: undefined symbol: unixd_config    [FAILED]

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, and this was the solution:

```
yum install php-fpm
```